# How to capture GOAWAY from a Linux VM (Centos)

Tags: packet-capture, packet-sniffer, grpc

Objective:
I'm troubleshooting integration between two service fleets proxied by Envoy (AWS AppMesh) using GRPC.
My GRPC clients never send traffic to the new GRPC servers (after scale-out).

Context:
GRPC servers are configured with `maxConnectionAge` to recycle connections every 30sec. For the context, that setup currently works in Prod on those services.
The only piece that changed here is Envoy that I'm currently testing as an alternative to current infra.

What I'm trying to do:
I'd like to sniff traffic from a GRPC server to see when it sends a GOAWAY and try to follow that up to the client, to actually see if the client tries reconnecting but always get the same servers from Envoy, of if it's something different.

And more generally speaking, I'd like to be able to sniff GRPC traffic that will for sure be helpful for my future self on other troubleshootings.

My service runs on a CentOs without UI.

Note: I'm conscious being able to sniff traffic may not be the best way to troubleshoot my issue, I'm happy if anyone share some thoughts about that. However I'm still interested to be able to sniff the traffic and see the HTTP 2 frames.

Thanks